# postgres extschema syntax error on postgresql anonymizer

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL Anonymizer on to an RDS (postgres 11) instance but I keep running into a syntax error when I run the `.sql` script when it tries to create some functions, specifically here: https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer/-/blob/master/anon.sql#L805

it throws this error:

```
psql:/postgresql_anonymizer/anon_standalone.sql:815: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 8:   SELECT encode(@extschema@.digest(concat(seed,salt),algorit...
```

I've ran it via `psql -h host -d db -f anon_standalone.sql` and also in `psql` like `\i /anon_standalone.sql` but still get the same error

I'm following the instructions here: https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/INSTALL/#install-in-the-cloud

Answer (score 0):

I work on the PostgreSQL Anonymizer extension, here's a quick answer:

In previous versions, the extension could be installed on various Database As A Service platforms (such as Amazon RDS). Starting with version 0.9, this is not possible anymore. We do not support the former standalone method. If privacy and anonymity are a concern to you, we encourage you to contact the customer services of these platforms and ask them if they plan to add this extension to their catalog.

Comment: Link to the docs: https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/INSTALL.html#install-in-the-cloud

Comment: Privacy is a concern indeed, and I'm going to ask Amazon, but I doubt the anon extension will be added quickly to RDS. Especially since the repo says: "This project is at an early stage of development, and should be used carefully.". I'm super interested in the extension, but we need anonymisation in the next month or so.

Comment: Can I use 0.8.1 on RDS then?

Comment: Hi ! 
Just to let know : version 1.0 is out and ready for production  https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-anonymizer-10-privacy-by-design-for-postgres-2452/